# Memoise Function Compilation Error in LINQpad

Tags: vb.net, functional-programming, linqpad

The following does not compile in LINQpad (Language=`VB Program`):

```
'    Hans-Christian Holm - Case study: Making use of functional programming techniques in .NET
'    [https://vimeo.com/97541187]
'    http://www.yr.no/

readonly Memos = new ConcurrentDictionary(of string, XElement)

function Memoise(f as Func(of XElement), key as string) as Func(of XElement)
    return function() Memos.GetOrAdd(key, function(k) f()) 'ERROR here!
end function

function ViewItem(temperature as integer) as XElement
    return <li><%= temperature %></li>
end function

function ViewList(temperatures as integer()) as XElement
    return <ul><%= temperatures.Select(addressof ViewItem) %></ul>
end function

function GetData() as integer()
    dim s as string = "Getting data..."
    s.Dump()
    return {2, 3}
end function

function ListComponent() as XElement
    dim data = GetData()
    return <div><%= ViewList(data) %></div>
end function

sub Main
    dim c = Memoise(addressof ListComponent, "my-component")
    c().Dump()
    c().Dump()
end sub
```

This is the error message:

```
Overload resolution failed because no Public 'GetOrAdd' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Function GetOrAdd(key As String, value As System.Xml.Linq.XElement) As System.Xml.Linq.XElement':
        Argument matching parameter 'value' cannot convert from 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of Object,XElement)' to 'XElement'.
    'Public Function GetOrAdd(key As String, valueFactory As System.Func(Of String,XElement)) As System.Xml.Linq.XElement':
        Argument matching parameter 'valueFactory' cannot convert from 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of Object,XElement)' to 'Func(Of String,XElement)'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LinqPad select **Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Compile VB queries in strict mode > True**; change your first line to:

```
readonly Memos as ConcurrentDictionary(of string, XElement) = new ConcurrentDictionary(of string, XElement)
```

and change `funcion(k)` to `function(k as string)` inside your `Memoise()` function.